# How to add xdb to an existing Sitecore instance

Tags: xdb

I have an existing Sitecore site with 9.3. It is a CMS only site. No Xdb databases, site, solr core's etc... I would now like to add Xdb to this site. The question is how? It seems like I need to use SIF to install, but can I do this once, and then manually add all the components to the different environments? Like can I do the install on my dev machine, then copy all the different pieces to QA and Prod, and just update Connection Strings, Thumbprints, etc... Or do I need to do a SIF install on each machine? Can I make SIF do an XDB only install? Oh, and also, do I have to have Sitecore Identity site for XDB? Currently Im using old style log in page.